# ngrep - possible to hide payloads?

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, http-headers

I use ngrep a lot to inspect HTTP headers to see what's going on. I use the `-q` flag for quiet output, but I really don't want to see the payloads, only the headers.

Is there a way to do this? My current command is:

```
ngrep 'Content-Length:' port 80 -t  -W byline -q
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting `-S` to a small number?

```
-S limitlen
  Set the upper limit on the size of packets that ngrep will look at. Useful for 
  looking at only the first N bytes of packets without changing the BPF snaplen.
```

Comment: I use `-S 0` and pipe it to `| grep T` so it only shows the source and destination header